# Live video streaming performance testing for 10k VU

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In basic terms, I want to make sure that our Livestreaming Shows can without issues have 10,000 viewers at one time. That the following things are working well:

- Video Quality
- Video Resolution
- Video Latency

Do this can be done using local machine , I read local machine cannot produce such huge number of requests.

Do I needed to purchase addition premium platform or it can be done using jmeter alone.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Do this can be done using local machine` - we don't know, it depends on your machine hardware specifications. I would take the following steps:

   - set up monitoring of the machine's resources consumption like CPU, RAM, etc. If you don't have better alternatives - you can go for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
   - make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load till 10 000 at the same time looking at the resources consumption
   - when any of monitored resources starts exceeding reasonable threshold, i.e. 90% of total available capacity stop the test and check how many users were online at this stage via i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) plugin

     **this is how many users you can simulate for particular this test from particular this machine**. If it's 10 000 - you're good to go with a single one, if it's less - divide 10 000 to the number of users you were able to mimic and this will be the number of machines of that hardware specifications you will need for the test
2. JMeter out of box can be run in the [clustered mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) so given you have the machines you can use as the load generators there is no need to purchase anything else. If you don't - you can rent VMs from i.e. [MS Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) or [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) or whatever is your favorite cloud provider. In this case you will need to pay for the machine/computing time according to the vendor price list
3. There are companies which offer "JMeter as a service", normally they charge more than cloud VM vendors but you won't need to worry about JMeter distributed configuration, results collection, etc. They are [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-load-testing/), [Flood.io](https://www.flood.io/tools/jmeter), [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2020/04/jmeter-cloud-load-testing/), etc.